# How to add multiple choices with tkinter ttk?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()
variable = StringVar(root)
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set('GB')
w = Combobox(root, values = choices)
w.pack(); root.mainloop()
choices = ['']
msedgelocation= 'my msedge location'
chromelocation= 'my chrome location'
if os.path.exists(msedgelocation):
# add msedge to choices
else:
if os.path.exists(chromelocation):
# add chrome to choices
```

This will only add 1 option, How do I change the script so it adds multiple options?
Preferably just code and an explanation, but anything helps. Thanks!

EDIT: Also a submit box would be nice

Comment: Your code will fail to executed.  Also code after tkinter mainloop will not be executed until the root window is destroyed.

Comment: what is the point: `import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *`? also import what You need only don't use `*`

Comment: also why would You put multiple statements in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved Your code a bit:

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import os


def get_choice(event):
    os.startfile(choices[event.widget.get()])


root = Tk()

variable = StringVar()
variable.set('GB')

choices = {'GB': 'gb.exe', 'AUS': 'aus.exe', 'USA': 'usa.exe', 'Chrome': 'chrome.exe'}


c_box = Combobox(root, values=list(choices.keys()), textvariable=variable, state='readonly')
c_box.pack()

c_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_choice)

root.mainloop()
```

First of I got all the info about the combobox [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-combobox/) where it was put in simple words.

The other thing is that You should name variables with meaningful variable names not just one letter names, especially if You plan on using the variable.

Also as I mentioned in the comments, it is suggested that You import only what You need, as You can see in my provided code.

Lastly, as @acw1668 already mentioned in comments the code after `.mainloop()` will only get executed when the window closes.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your code, but is there a way to change the code so it only adds an option if os.path.exists? @Matiiss

Comment: @MeWhenBonk yes there certainly is an option, I edited my code a bit to add that option, but that is the simplest variation, so it wouldn't be great for checking tens of thousands of paths since then You would have to write that many `if statements` but for simple stuff this works, also it will list the whole path in the combobox

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matiiss , But i can't figure out how to, instead of print 'Selected Chrome' , os.startfile('chrome.exe') if Chrome is selected, Could you help me with that?

Comment: @MeWhenBonk did that too, a bit different approach in this case since You have to use dictionaries (although possible to use two lists or something like that, just dictionaries will be easier).  Also I removed that if statement but I hope You got that already.